# Why does gcc save r4 in arm FIQ interrupt handlers?

Tags: arm, interrupt-handling

Consider the following C code:

```
extern void dummy(void);

void foo1(void) __attribute__(( interrupt("IRQ") ));
void foo2(void) __attribute__(( interrupt("FIQ") ));

void foo1() {
  dummy();
  return;
}
void foo2() {
  dummy();
  return;
}
```

The code produced by arm gnueabi gcc is basically this:

```
foo1:
    sub lr, lr, #4
    stmfd   sp!, {r0, r1, r2, r3, ip, lr}
    bl  dummy
    ldmfd   sp!, {r0, r1, r2, r3, ip, pc}^
foo2:
    sub lr, lr, #4
    stmfd   sp!, {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, lr}
    bl  dummy
    ldmfd   sp!, {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, pc}^
```

The code for foo1 does not hold any surprises. `r0-r3` and `ip` are saved, because the call to dummy may change their value. Also, after correcting `lr`, it is pushed and popped into pc in the end. This is fairly standard.

However, the code for foo2 is surprising. Saving the value of `ip` is not required, as it is a banked register. But that gcc saves `r4` is surprising.

So why does gcc save r4? I don't see any reason to do that, since the call to dummy will not corrupt this register.

Comment: for reference https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/config/arm/arm.c#L18976

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25282466/1163019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it does it to ensure 8-byte stack alignment required by EABI. The actual register used does not matter, it could be r12 or anything else - it's just used for the extra 4-byte adjustment.