# ARM GCC Cortex-M7 bare-metal compiler flags for proper floating-point stack alignment?

Tags: gcc, floating-point, arm

Using the **arm-none-eabi-gcc** compiler from ARM I find that `printf("%lf")` prints garbage values when the stack is not 8-byte-aligned prior to calling. If I manually align the stack, then it always works:

```
// This always works, but fails without the get/set_MSP manipulation when
// the MSP is not 8-byte-aligned
unsigned msp = __get_MSP();
__set_MSP(msp & ~7);

    // Prints wrong floating-point value when stack is not 8-byte-aligned.
    // No difference using %f vs. %lf
    printf("%lf\n", 1.234);

__set_MSP(msp);
```

`arm-none-eabi-gcc -v` returns:

gcc version 10.2.1 20201103 (release) (GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain 10-2020-q4-major)

and relevant compiler flags are:

`-O3 -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fno-strict-aliasing -std=gnu++17 -fno-rtti -fno-use-cxa-atexit`

Can anyone suggest any compiler flags I may be missing (or shouldn't be specifying?) -- or other solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: gcc with these flags seems to generate code that maintains stack alignment: https://godbolt.org/z/WT1a7xKa9.  Are you certain that your startup code aligns the stack correctly before `main()` is called?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why does AAPCS require 8byte stack alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282466/why-procedure-call-standard-for-the-arm-architecture-aapcs-requires-sp-to-be).  If I say this is a duplicate your question will be automatically closed.  Please read the link and see if you see your question as different (and please explain why).  An 8byte aligned stack is required by the AAPCS standard.  Also, [Cortex-m7 and stack](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/f/cortex-m-forum/6344/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-64-bit-aligned-stack-pointer-address)

Comment: @NateEldredge got it right ... I was mucking with the stack at other layers of the implementation and found a bug that left the stack non-8-byte aligned. Fixing the root cause fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Gcc is just generating code that produces the 8 byte alignment that is mandated by the [ARM ABI specification](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/releases). This is specifically pointed out in [ABI for the Arm® Architecture Advisory Note](https://github.com/ARM-software/abi-aa/blob/60a8eb8c55e999d74dac5e368fc9d7e36e38dda4/advnote132/advnote132.rst)

From Section 3.1 "The need to align SP to a multiple of 8 at conforming call sites"

> In return for preserving the natural alignment of data, conforming code
> is permitted to rely on that alignment. To support aligning data allocated on the stack, the stack pointer (SP) is required to be 8-byte aligned on entry to a conforming function...